# PHP Postgresql add data to database via webbrowser

Tags: php, postgresql, input

I am figuring out how to add data to a Postgresql-database via a dynamic php-based webpage. In the book "PHP and Postgresql: advanced web programming" (2002) I found some interesting code for setting up a content management system (see below). Everything goes fine when I load the data in Firefox or Chrome, but when I press the submit button no data from the fields is added to the database. Nothing happens. I wonder, is this code outdated (book is from 2002) or is there something else wrong or missing? The connection with the database seems fine (no error).

```
 <?php

    $data .= "<html>
            <body>
            <h1>Content Management Tool</h1>
            Edit the table <br>";

    # connecting to the database
    $dbh = pg_connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres host=localhost password=");
    if      (!$dbh)
    {
            die ("cannot connect to database<br>\n");
    }
    # checking for insert
    if      ($number_of_fields)
    {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $tab VALUES (";
            for     ($i = 1; $i < $number_of_fields - 1; $i++)
            {
                    $sql .= "'${$i}', ";
            }
            $max = $number_of_fields - 1;
            $sql .= "'${$max}')";
            $ret = pg_query($dbh, $sql) or
                    die ("cannot execute UPDATE operation<br>\n");
    }
    # retrieving a list of all tables in the database
    $sql = "SELECT oid, * FROM message";
    $res = @pg_query($dbh, $sql) or
            die ("cannot retrieve list of tables");

    # displaying list
    $data .= "<br><b>Details:</b><br>\n";
    $rows = pg_num_rows($res);
    $fields = pg_num_fields($res);

    # displaying header of table
    $table .= "<table border=3><tr>\n";
    for     ($i = 1; $i < $fields; $i++)
    {
            $table .= "<th>".
            pg_field_name($res, $i)."</th>";
    }
    $data .= $table."<th>action</th>\n";
    $data .= "</tr>\n";

    # displaying data
    $data .= '<form action="detail.php" method="post">';

    for     ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++)
    {
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $line = pg_fetch_row($res, $i);

            for     ($j = 1; $j < $fields; $j++)
            {
                    $data .= "<td>";
                    $data .= $line[$j];
                    $data .= "</td>";
            }
            $data .= '<td><a href="action.php?act=delete&oid='.
                    $line[0].'&tab='.$tab.'">Delete</a> </td> ';
            $data .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    $data .= "</table>\n";
    $data .= "<br><b>Add data to the table</b><br>\n";

    # displaying HTML for inserting data
    $data .= $table;
    $data .= "<tr>";
    for     ($i = 1; $i < $fields; $i++)
    {
            $data .= "<td>".
                    '<input type="text" name="'.$i.'"></td>';
    }
    $data .= "</tr>\n";
    $data .= "</table>\n";
    $data .= '<input type="hidden" name="number_of_fields" '.
            "value=\"$fields\"><br><br>";
    $data .= '<input type="hidden" name="tab" value="'.$tab.'">';
    $data .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" >';
    $data .= "</form>\n";

    echo $data, $tail;
 ?>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE message
(
id integer,
tstamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
who text,
message text
)
WITH (
OIDS=TRUE
);
ALTER TABLE message
OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE message TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE message TO public;
```

Comment: Don't **EVER** put up a "delete" operation as a simple link. You might just live long enough to utterly regret it: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Answer (score 1):

"when I press the submit button no data from the fields is added to the database"

You are using `if ($number_of_fields)` to check if data was submitted.
What you might additionally do to see, if data is incomming, is to place a `var_dump($_POST);` at the top after the opening `<php?` tag.
That will show you the "incoming" data, after you pressed submit.

You might also place an additional `echo 'Inserting Values';` inside the insert code block.
That will show that $number_of_fields is set and the INSERT is going to happen next.

Now let's take a closer look at the insert code-block.
You have a for-loop there, iterating over $i and appending ${i} to the SQL.
That doesn't look right. I believe that `$_POST[$i]` would be a better fit here.
You might try a `var_dump($_POST[$i]);` inside the loop to see, if you get some data values. If yes, then append that to the SQL.

```
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $tab VALUES (";
            for     ($i = 1; $i < $number_of_fields - 1; $i++)
            {
                    $sql .= "'${$i}', "; // <--- $_POST[$i] ???
            }
            $max = $number_of_fields - 1;
            $sql .= "'${$max}')";

            var_dump($sql); // <--- see, if SQL statement contains your data
```

You might also place a `var_dump($sql);` before the `pg_query()` function, to see, if the SQL statement contains your data, which would be sent to the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your input. According to a debug tool for PHP coding, the variables "tab" and "number_of_fields" aren't defined: Notice: Undefined variable: number_of_fields in C:\Users\marko\Documents\NuSphere PhpED\Projects\detail.php on line 16. Is this correct?

Notice: Undefined variable: tab in C:\Users\marko\Documents\NuSphere PhpED\Projects\detail.php on line 29
cannot retrieve list of tables)